# How force a template file in tt_news LIST?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

I have a list in tt_news and use many folders with tt_news records. I want to use a different template in this list when I filter and display specific category.

My Typoscript is:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_ttnews|place|0 = 79]
    #Display list of specific category   
    plugin.tt_news.templateFile = fileadmin/templates/plugins/tt_news/different.html
[else]
    #General display list
    plugin.tt_news.templateFile = fileadmin/templates/plugins/tt_news/general.html
[end]
```

I have used  `plugin.tt_news.templateFile` and `plugin.tt_news.file.templateFile` but don't work. I am using the last version of tt_news and TYPO3 6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Typoscript way did not resolve this, I do not why? For we needed we have use a category and marker in the template of tt_news and create a logic in frontend through JS for resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

"`plugin.tt_news.templateFile`" is right, i think there is a problem in "`[globalVar = GP:tx_ttnews|place|0 = 79]`" you should close global with "`[global]`" instead of "`[end]`". Try this if it is helpful to you.